# Finding distance and time from multiple points to nearest destination(s) using ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

I am trying to compute the distance and time taken for each origin (40,000+ house points) to the nearest train station (there are 111 of them). How can I do that in ArcGIS?

So example Houses H1 to H10 nearest station is S1, and H11 to H30 is S2, so on...

*Update: The distance would be network distance not straight line.*

Comment: Are you looking for the shortest straight line path, or along a road network?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I am looking for road network distance.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [OD cost matrix analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/od-cost-matrix.htm) in Network Analyst extension. Load all of your house points as origins and all your train stations as destinations. Then specify that you want to get the route only to one destination (which would be the closest) - the parameter is called `Destinations To Find`.

This will generate a number of routes (remember that you won't get actual routes shapes created as this is a very expensive operation), but you are not interested in them, so choose for `Output shape type` value `None`.

Comment: Where do I specify the route to only one destination? Also would using Closest Facility be any different?

Comment: You do it on the Analysis Settings tab, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/GUID-DDBB933B-38D3-4A67-A9D4-A8EEFFD9DC08-web.png, read through the Help page to get started. Closest Facility (CF) would also do the trick, but you have so many routes to build - the CF would be so much slower than OD because it is not optimized for solving so many routes at the same time.